# How to specify the equivalence between two time periods? (e.g. "the beginning of the war was July 7")

Tags: verbos, tiempo

Can someone give me various ways to translate the following sentences?

> The beginning of the war was July 7.

> The period of mourning was July 7 - July 14.

I ask because I'm trying to explore the uses of "ir," and I suspect that "ir could be used in these sentences.

I guess it would be more natural to say something like "the war began on July 7," or "we mourned from July 7 to July 14." I'm just trying to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have some suggestions [including the verb "ir"] :

> The beginning of the war was July 7.

- El inicio de la guerra fue el 7 de julio [literal translation]
- La guerra comenzó (se inició / empezó) el 7 de julio.

> The period of mourning was July 7 - July 14.

- El periodo de duelo (luto) fue del 7 al 14 de julio

Answer (score 1):

> The beginning of the war was July 7.

- El comienzo de la guerra fue el 7 de Julio

> The period of mourning was July 7 - July 14.

- El periodo de luto fue del 7 al 14 de Julio.
- El periodo luctuoso se llevo acabo entre el 7 y el 14 de Julio.
- El periodo luctuoso fue desde el 7 hasta el 14 de Julio, ambos inclusive.

Comment: Thanks @Diego! I'm making the other response as the answer since it is older, but this was just as good.

Comment: Gracias a ti por el comentario.